# Combining two multidimensional arrays taking structure of one and content of the other in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I'm somewhat new with PHP. Is there a way to merge the two following arrays so that the [2181] and [2180] keys (and all of their content) in the second array can replace the two datetime objects in the first array while still maintaining the structure of the first array? The datetime objects from the first array will have the same [date] key value as the [date] key value from the second array at the [2182] and [2180] index, although I'm not sure if this shared key=>value will be necessary to merge the arrays correctly.

```
 1.)  Array 
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => DateTime Object
                            (
                                [date] => 2017-04-23 13:35:17.000000
                                [timezone_type] => 3
                                [timezone] => America/Denver
                            )

                                    )
                [1] => Array
                     (
                        [0] => DateTime Object
                            (
                                [date] => 2017-04-22 13:35:17.000000
                                [timezone_type] => 3
                                [timezone] => America/Denver
                            )
                    )


 2.) Array
    (
        [2182] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2182
                [date] => 2017-04-23
                [door] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 2999
                            )
                        )

                  )

        [2180] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2180
                [date] => 2017-04-22
                [door] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 2994
                            )

                    )
                )
```

This final array is how I need it to be structured.

```
 3.)  Array 
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [2182] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2182
                        [date] => 2017-04-23
                        [door] => Array
                            (
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 2999
                                    )
                                )
                     )

                                    )
                [1] => Array
                     (
                        [2180] => Array
                     (
                          [id] => 2180
                          [date] => 2017-04-22
                          [door] => Array
                            (
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 2994
                                    )
                               )
                        )
    )
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want to replace datetime object ?

Comment: Are the two arrays always in the same order, or do you have to match the elements using the `date` keys?

Comment: The `date` element contains a date and time in the first array, but just a date in the second array. Can there be multiple times on the same day?

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear. Both of the first two arrays are subsets of two larger arrays that I spliced for the brevity of this post. Is there a way to match the date keys? Is it possible to replace the datetime objects with the [2182] and [2180] keys by matching the dates? The first array is a product of a function that groups the dates within the second interval by distance between dates and I'd like to maintain those subgroups while inserting the additional information that is not date-related from the second array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what are you exactly asking.

Given the final array as you want in your question, you can do like this

```
<?php

$date = [[0=>new dateTime()], [new dateTime()]];// why this array if you are not using..

$arr = [
    2182=>["id"=>2182,"date"=>"2017-04-5", "door"=>[1=>["id"=>2999]]],
    2180=>["id"=>2180,"date"=>"2017-04-22", "door"=>[1=>["id"=>2994]]]
];

print_r(($arr));

$newArr = [];
foreach($arr as $a){
    $newArr[] = $a;
}


print_r($newArr);
```

Tested [online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2a91359d54fbfda65d75f09bd3c0898c55d0e378)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The first array from my question with the datetime objects holds a structure (which isn't immediately visible in my question and is a subgrouping of of the dates based on the interval between them) that I want to maintain.  Is there a way to do so by matching the date keys and injecting/replacing the datetime objects with in the first array with all the information under the [2182] and [2180] keys in the second array?

Comment: This response creates an array that looks identical to the one I'm looking to create but is not a combination of the two arrays so I wouldn't be able to use reuse this with different arrays of dates to produce the results I'm looking for but again I appreciate the response!